# Async Jasmine unit test wrong order

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, async-await, jasmine

I have a `onBlur` function which gets executed when the blur on an input is activated. Inside this async `onBlur` function I `await` the response from another function. When I try to test this the order of execution seems wrong. I've put in three console.logs() to inspect the order of execution which seems to be incorrect.

What is causing this order to go wrong? Wouldn't `nextTick()` ensure that the `async` functions need to be finished before the test is concluded?

```
it('executes startDate when blur is triggered on search', async function(done) {
      // GIVEN an instantiated SearchDate
      // WHEN validateStartDate is spied upon and blur is triggered
      const spyValidateStartDate = spyOn(SearchDate.methods, 'validateStartDate').and.callThrough();

      wrapper = shallowMount(
        Search,
        {
          localVue: this.localVue,
          propsData: props,
        },
      );

      const searchStartDateElement = wrapper.find('#searchStartDate');
      searchStartDateElement.element.value = '01-01-2018';
      await searchStartDateElement.trigger('blur');

      // THEN expect datepickerStartDate to have the correct date
      wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
        expect(spyValidateStartDate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        console.log('3');
        expect(wrapper.vm._data.datepickerStartDate).toEqual(new Date('2018-01-01'));
        done();
      });
    });
```

And the blur function in Vue

```
async onBlur(event) {
      console.log('1');
      this.datepickerStartDate = await this.validateDateField(event.target.getAttribute('name'), event.target.value);
      console.log('2');
    },
```

The current order of the `console.log()` is `1, 3, 2`

validateDateField function

```
    async validateDateField(name, value) {
      const valid = await this.$validator.validate(name);
      if (!valid || !value) {
        return null;
      }

      const splittedInput = value.split('-');
      return new Date(`${ splittedInput[2] }-${ splittedInput[1] }-${ splittedInput[0] }`);
    },
```

Comment: "Wouldn't nextTick() ensure that the async functions need to be finished before the test is concluded?" - certainly no. You cannot expect this, unless you're sure that api you use deals with promises. Promises are ignored in event listeners and a lot of other places. The way this should be tested depends on validateDateField. Why is it asynchronous?

Comment: The validateDateField requires a value from the $.validator which is async. I've added the validateDateField function to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

`nextTick` can be used in promise control flow but it can't be aware of any asynchronous actions that happen in user code. The problem is that is `validateDateField` is asynchronous but not waited in the test, this results in race condition. A promise that it returns should be chained in the test to maintain the correct order of execution.

Modern testing frameworks support promises, it's an antipattern to use `async` and `done` together. This makes a test more complex and error-prone. This may prevent errors from being correctly handled. In case `done` is not called due to some condition, this results in test timeout.

It can be:

```
async function() {
  const spyValidateStartDate = spyOn(SearchDate.methods, 'validateStartDate').and.callThrough();
  ...

  searchStartDateElement.trigger('blur');
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  expect(spyValidateStartDate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  const dataResult = await spyValidateStartDate.calls.first().returnValue;
  // Can also assert the result for more rigid test
  expect(wrapper.vm._data.datepickerStartDate).toEqual(new Date('2018-01-01'));
}
```